# Plain Text Files Without Text Mimetypes

Tags: mime-types

There are a lot of file types that are categorized under `application` even though they contain only plain text.  For example, `application/javascript`.  Where can I find a list of all of these miscategorized mime types?

In other words, how can I determine if it is safe to view a file as plain text?